# Https Implementation in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, https

How i can implement https login in asp.net and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you your ok with a normal login page.  So for ssl buy your certificate and install http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-support/cert_installation/iis_ssl_certificate_5x.html

Then make sure you login page redirects to https rather than http.

```
        if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Replace("http", "https"), true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you do for the "regular" login. You only have to enable SSL in IIS. For this you will need a server certificate.
[Read This](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_ssl_on_your_website_with_iis.htm)
[And This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)

Answer (score 0):

As with all things .net, first check out what The Gu has to say: [Protected ASP.Net Site in 24 lines of code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx). That should cover the basics of creating a protected site.

In order to protect the page with SSL, you will need a server certificate. Installing one with IIS is covered here: [IIS 5/6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875) and [IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/). Some specifics of how to secure ASP.Net in this manner are covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx). Dominick Baier's blog is also always a good source of info on .net security matters, and he has an old post on partially-SSL secured ASP.Net sites [here](http://www.leastprivilege.com/PartiallySSLSecuredWebAppsWithASPNET.aspx) that could be helpful depending upon the requirements you are working with.